# jupyter / Anaconda3 path in AWS EC2

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, anaconda, jupyter

I have followed all of the below steps, yet the wrong python is loading up in EC2 - 2.7 and not the desired 3.6.

Here is what I have done.

1). Created and launched EC2 instance

2). Opened up security groups as needed

3). SSH into the instance using Putty

4). Downloaded the desired anaconda distribution with `wget https://repo.continuum.io/repo/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

5). Install with `bash Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

6). Change the path variable: `vim .bashrc.`

7). Add the path and save changes

8). `which python /usr/bin/anaconda3` which returns `/usr/bin/python` `/usr/bin/python`

9). type `source .bashrc`

10) **fingers crossed** type `python` only to see python2.7 **MEGA disappointment**

Did I miss a step? What did I do wrong?

Thanks, Stack.